# how to complete the following R code

Tags: r

I want to use the function to calculate the arl of cusum 
however I meet a problem 
when I run the code 
it shows "Error in if (r[i] > h1) break : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" to me. 
I don't know how to write the correct code

```
myfun2<-function(c1,h1){
r=rep(0,500)
for (i in 1:499){
r[i+1]<-max(0,c1[i]+0.85*r[i])
(arl<-i)
if(r[i]>h1) break 
}
result<-arl
}
m=sapply(c,h=0.1865,myfun2)
```

Comment: In your `sapply` call you refer to `h=0.1865` instead of `h1`, thus, `h1` in missing in the `if` clause

Comment: Further: `sapply()` is splitting your vector `c` to elements and puts the elements one by one to your function. So you can not use `c1[i]` in your function. Is `c` a vector? Or is it a list of vectors? Please edit your question to make it [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Tom due to partial matching of argument names, `h` is sufficient.

Comment: now I already know how to edit and in order to make the code efficient I edit the code to this.                                                 
 myfun2<-function(n1,h1){
  r=0
  i=0
  for (x in n1){
  b<-max(0,x+0.85*r)
  r=b
  if(r>h1) break
    i<-i+1
  }
  return(i)
}
arl=myfun2(ny,0.1865)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jogo already pointed out the problem. `sapply` is going through each element of `c`. Because your example is not fully reproducible it's hard to know what `c` is but if it's a vector, here's the problem (notice the print statements):

```
> myfun2 <- function(c1, h1) {
+   r <- rep(0, 500)
+   for (i in 1:499) {
+     print(sprintf("c1[i]: %s, h1: %s, r[i] %s", c1[i], h1, r[i]))
+     r[i + 1] <- max(0, c1[i] + 0.85*r[i])
+     arl <- i
+     if (r[i] > h1) break 
+   }
+   arl
+ }
> 
> set.seed(357)
> c1 <- rnorm(10)
> m <- sapply(c1, h = 0.1865, FUN = myfun2)
[1] "c1[i]: -1.24111730713255, h1: 0.1865, r[i] 0"
[1] "c1[i]: NA, h1: 0.1865, r[i] 0"
[1] "c1[i]: NA, h1: 0.1865, r[i] NA"
Error in if (r[i] > h1) break : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Error during wrapup:
```

Answer (score 0):

now I already know how to edit and in order to make the code efficient I edit the code to this.

```
myfun2<-function(n1,h1){
  r=0
  i=0
  for (x in n1){
  b<-max(0,x+0.85*r)
  r=b
  if(r>h1) break
    i<-i+1
  }
  return(i)
}
arl=myfun2(ny,0.1865)
```